# How can I mount a sdcard and view it in /dev of a virtualbox guest

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox, sd-card

I'm trying to insert a SD card into my laptop (it's got a side slot for one) and have it show up on the guest machine running in a virtual box.

Host: Windows 7 64 for x86
Guest: Ubuntu 64bit

I want to configure things such that when I insert the SDcard into my laptop and my virtual box session is running I want to be able to see the device show up in `/dev/sdX` on my virtual machine.

Anyone know a way to do that? None of the settings seem to deal with SD cards.

---

EDIT:
It was suggested I create a rawdisk with the VBoxManager.exe with elevated privlages, I attempted it, but it fails for other reasons:

> > C:>"Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage" internalcommands createrawvmdk
> >     -filename MySSDDisk.vmdk -rawdisk \.\PHYSICALDRIVE3
> >     
> > VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to create the VirtualBox object!
> >     
> > VBoxManage.exe: error: Code CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE (0x80080005) - Server execu
> >     tion failed (extended info not available)
> >     
> > VBoxManage.exe: error: Most likely, the VirtualBox COM server is not running or
> >     failed to start.

Comment: Aren't SD cards shown up as USB devices in VirtualBox? Is it necessary for you that it is always the same `/dev/sdX`? And finally did you consider using a shared folder?

Answer (score 2):

From the Windows host determine the physical drive

```
wmic diskdrive list > drives.txt
notepad drives.txt
```

Once you know your drive, you can attach it as a raw disk. Example below uses PhysicalDrive2.
The following command must be done with elevated privileges:

```
VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename MySSDDisk.vmdk -rawdisk \\.\PhysicalDrive2
```

Attach the disk to the Virtual box and you should see the /dev/sd*x* when you start up Ubuntu

Comment: Got to give a +1 for the idea, but seems like it's not working for some reason. I'll have to dig into the failure unless you know why it's giving a server execution failure

Comment: Mike did you try also \\.\PhysicalDrive3  (no caps, and extra slash)? But you might be running into some other exotic thing.

Comment: Yeah, slashes and/or caps don't seem to effect the end result at all